# How do I fix this incorrect emulator command line run by VS 2013 MDA when I target Android Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

When I try to use "Android Emulator" as the target in Visual Studio for my Cordova app (running VS Tools for Cordova latest in VS 2013), I get about 6 or 7 errors. I noticed that the command line that VS tries to launch is missing quotes around the path to node.exe and uses double quotes around the path to emulator.js.

If I paste this into a cmd prompt and correct the quote problem, the emulator starts correctly. How can I fix this?

Here is the command line VS tries to run:

Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe ""C:\Users\Jason Learmouth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js"" --platform android --path "c:\code..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue which will be fixed in next update. Workaround is to use user name without any spaces. Visual Studio is putting double double quotes because of space in emulator.js path like `C:\Users\**Jason Learmouth**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js`